# Вывести ответ в массиве

Tags: javascript, html

```
 var weight = document.querySelectorAll('.weight');
 var shipping_cost = [];
 [].forEach.call(weight, function(weight) {
 var arr_shipping_cost = (weight.innerHTML * result).toFixed(7);
 shipping_cost.push(arr_shipping_cost)
 });
 console.log(shipping_cost);

var weight - это массив из чисел  var weight = [120.00,150.00,230.00,20.00]

result = это число пример 0.025


console.log(shipping_cost); получаю результат виде массива
["0.7987291", "0.7566907", "0.7566907", "0.7777099", "0.7566907"]
```

пример немного изменил так как я массив получаю `var weight = document.querySelectorAll('.weight');`

Как можно вставить полученные данные в массив

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
<tr>
  <td class="text-left shipping_cost"></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var weight = [120.00,250.00,25.00,32.00];
    var result = 0.004;
                var shipping_cost = [];
                [].forEach.call(weight, function(weight) {
                    var arr_shipping_cost = (weight * result);
                    shipping_cost.push(arr_shipping_cost)
                });
                console.log(shipping_cost);
    </script>
```

Comment: Перемудрили, `weight = weight.map( e => e * 0.004 )` — всё)

Comment: Спасибо, но все же хотелось бы понять как можно вывести результаты  `<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
<tr>
  <td class="text-left shipping_cost"></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решения которое мне помогло вывести данные

```
 $(".shipping_cost").text((i)=>shipping_cost[i]);
```